# Optimum way to set up user based windows services?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, windows-services

I am using .NET Framework 4.0. I want to set up an application where this application produce reports in PDF files and send an email to reporting officers. There are certain users where they can set an report criteria and set dates and time to receive this email of report. This repeat occurrence might depends on users, they might set weekly, biweekly report schedule with time.

I think windows services is better way to do this. but again this a overhead on server and SQL server that services thread continuously run and check for criteria to run store procedure and send an email if user has set weekly or bi weekly.

Can suggest if it is possible in ASP.NET MVC 4 or in SQL Server 2012.

Can anyone suggest better or optimum approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You already have [SQL Server Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx). This can write the reports, [render them as PDF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291.aspx), keep a [schedule when to run them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159767.aspx), and [deliver them via email](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx), including embedded reports.